# How do I set value of DateTextBox?

Tags: dojo

So basically I have these two DateTextBoxes and I want to copy the value from one to another? Sounds easy, right? Still, it is not...
I tried to do it this way:

```
dojo.byId("datetextbox1").value = dojo.byId("datetextbox2").value;
```

it actually looks like the value changes as the content of the field changes, but it doesn't really. When I inspect the element with firefox it still contains the old value in the code and when I try to submit the form, the old value is sent!
So my question is: how should I change that damn value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to set the value on the widget and not directly on the node.

```
dijit.byId("datetextbox1").set('value', dijit.byId("datetextbox2").get('value'));
```

dijit.byId grabs widgets, dojo.byId grabs dom nodes